# Element XML parsing not giving proper result

Tags: python, xml

I have sample below XML file and I am trying to generate below JSON but I am not geeting expected result it is only add one document in dictionary.

```
Sample Input XML:
    <results status="passed">
        <num-records>2</num-records>
        <records>
            <volume-info>
                <flexible-volume-info>
                    <agg-name>aggr1_split</aggregate-name>
                </flexible-volume-info>
                <volume-name>volume1</volume-name>
                <volume-size>
                    <actual-size>44</actual-volume-size>
                    <afs-avail>90</afs-avail>
                </volume-size>
            </volume-info>
            <volume-info>
                <flexible-volume-info>
                    <agg-name>aggr2_split</aggregate-name>
                </flexible-volume-info>
                <volume-name>volume2</volume-name>
                <volume-size>
                    <actual-size>10</actual-volume-size>
                    <afs-avail>14</afs-avail>
                </volume-size>
            </volume-info>
        </records>
    </results>
```

Expected Output:
     {
        "agg-name": "aggr1_split",
        "volume-name": "volume1",
        "actual-size": "44"
     },
     {
        "agg-name": "aggr2_split",
        "volume-name": "volume2",
        "actual-size": "10"
     }

```
Sample code:    
result = {}
for child in root.iter("records"):
    result['agg-name'] = child.find('volume-info/flexible-volume-info/agg-name').text
    result['volume-name'] = child.find('volume-info/volume-name').text
    result['actual-size'] = child.find('volume-info/volume-size/actual-size').text
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output would be a dictionary which contained multiple identical keys which is not possible. You either need to choose different keys for each iteration of your loop or better still have a list of dictionaries:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_data = """<results status="passed">
    <num-records>2</num-records>
    <records>
        <volume-info>
            <flexible-volume-info>
                <agg-name>aggr1_split</agg-name>
            </flexible-volume-info>
            <volume-name>volume1</volume-name>
            <volume-size>
                <actual-size>44</actual-size>
                <afs-avail>90</afs-avail>
            </volume-size>
        </volume-info>
        <volume-info>
            <flexible-volume-info>
                <agg-name>aggr2_split</agg-name>
            </flexible-volume-info>
            <volume-name>volume2</volume-name>
            <volume-size>
                <actual-size>10</actual-size>
                <afs-avail>14</afs-avail>
            </volume-size>
        </volume-info>
    </records>
</results>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)


results = []

for child in root.iter("volume-info"):
    result = {}
    print(child)
    result['agg-name'] = child.find('flexible-volume-info/agg-name').text
    result['volume-name'] = child.find('volume-name').text
    result['actual-size'] = child.find('volume-size/actual-size').text

    results.append(result)

print(results)
```

This would give you:

```
[{'agg-name': 'aggr1_split', 'volume-name': 'volume1', 'actual-size': '44'}, {'agg-name': 'aggr2_split', 'volume-name': 'volume2', 'actual-size': '10'}]
```

Your XML is also badly formed, the open and closing tags do not always match.

Comment: Both are individual documents kind of thing, so if i can get list of dictionaries also fine for me. Problem i am getting is root.iter is not getting in loop it is always giving one element only.Thanks